# Simple Javascript Scope HowTo and Examples

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, scopes

I am trying to develop a simple Scope for Ubuntu Phone (BQ 4.5 particularly). The scope's task should be just to display (and refresh) one web page directly in the scope, i.e. not to open a separate "window" for it (as [addtodash](https://github.com/rschroll/addtodash) does). The page can be generally any web page, but I want it to display my personal simple web page with a list of tasks, events etc.

I suppose that the simplest case should be to develop a JavaScript Scope. I was able to prepare and build the example weather scope as described in https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/scopes/tutorials/developing-scopes-javascript and install and run it on the phone. But this example is oriented to searching and displaying results from a list. How should this be changed to the (more simple) case of just displaying a web page content?

Is there some other documentation for JavaScript scopes available? 
Are there more JavaScript scope examples?

The only sources of information I was able to find are:

- the above mentioned tutorial - https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/scopes/tutorials/developing-scopes-javascript/
- very terse Javascript Scopes API reference - http://people.canonical.com/~davidcalle/unity-js-scopes-0.1/doc/
- an example of github search scope - http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~davidc3/+junk/github-js-scope/view/head:/src/githubscope.js

That's all - really not enough to develop something simple but different.